# BGL Interior properties for implicit graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm trying to use the A* search from Boost BGL on an implicit graph. I have implemented my own graph type which models the concept of Graph and IncidenceGraph. According to the documentation of A*, I should be using the astar_search_no_init function with implicit graphs.

Just to get the whole thing working, I have tried to implement dummy versions of all of the needed concepts. This includes the graph, the visitor, the heuristic and the vertex type. My main function looks like this

```
int main()
{
   graph g;
   // The vertex type is a simple wrapper for int.
   vertex start(1);
   vertex goal(10);

   boost::astar_search_no_init(g, start, heuristic(), 
        boost::visitor(visitor(goal)));
}
```

Without specifying any of the named parameters, the implementation should be using some default values. Apparently these default values require some support from my graph. The graph looks like this:

```
struct graph
{
   typedef void adjacency_iterator;
   typedef void in_edge_iterator;
   typedef void vertex_iterator;
   typedef void edge_iterator;
   typedef void vertices_size_type;

   typedef void edge_iterator;
   typedef void edges_size_type;

   typedef vertex vertex_descriptor;
   typedef double edge_descriptor;
   typedef boost::directed_tag directed_category;
   typedef boost::disallow_parallel_edge_tag edge_parallel_category;
   typedef boost::incidence_graph_tag traversal_category;

   typedef std::vector<double>::iterator out_edge_iterator;
   typedef int degree_size_type;
};
```

When compiling, the first and the most interesting error is this:

error C2039: 'edge_property_type' : is not a member of 'graph'

From what I understand, I need to add properties for my graph. I believe these properties should be interior properties. My question is: how do I add interior properties for my own implicit graph type?

Comment: (At least partially) solved, the example at https://github.com/wpm/Boost-Implicit-Graph-Example/wiki/Ring-Graph is pretty illuminating.

Comment: Do you still get this problem with the newest version of Boost?  Some algorithms had bugs that caused messages like this in the past.