# Why does BGL A* require the implicit graph to model VertexListGraph?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, a-star, boost-graph

A more specific follow-up question to my earlier one [BGL Interior properties for implicit graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620613/bgl-interior-properties-for-implicit-graph)

The Boost BGL has a version of the A* algorithm that is supposed to work with implicit graphs, namely the astar_search_no_init() function. The implicit graphs can be modeled as IncidenceGraphs. The [documentation of A*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html) says "Please note that astar_search_no_init() must be used for implicit graphs; the basic astar_search() function requires a graph that models the Vertex List Graph concept. Both versions also require the graph type to model the Incidence Graph concept".

Doesn't this mean that the graph does *not* have to model the Vertex List Graph concept? If this is the case, am I missing something since I am unable to find *any* versions of the function astar_search_no_init() that would use IncidenceGraphs? There are two versions of astar_search_no_init() available, and both of them seem to work with VertexListGraphs. I am using Boost 1.48 and the A* is in the file astar_search.hpp.

I don't see how it would even make sense to require the implicit graph to model the Vertex List Graph in the first place. The documentation is quite confusing and misleading to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean "two versions of astar_search_no_init(), and both of them seem to work _only_ on VertexListGraphs" ? The two concepts are essentially orthogonal, so it's not surprising that there are VertexListGraphs which are also IncidenceGraphs.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, this is what I meant. Both of them seem to work only with VertexListGraphs. The (formal) names in the .hpp are atleast conflicting and thus misleading with the documentation, but I'll give it a try soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for implicit graphs was added in [r50803](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/50803) on January 27, 2009, to fix [Bug #829](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/829). The fix was not to rely on `num_vertices` or utilize any other requirement of graph types modeling the [VertexListGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/VertexListGraph.html) concept.

So, even though the template type parameter is named `VertexListGraph`, it should just work with graph types that only model the [IncidenceGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/IncidenceGraph.html) concept.

Answer (score 2):

The graph concepts are ordered themselves; here's a nice graph of graph concepts ;)

[image: Boost graph concepts]

As you can see, the fact that the the `Incidence Graph` concept required by `astar_search_no_init()` is unrelated to `Vertex List Graph` concept. I.e. each concept can be modelled independently. So, it's sufficient for your graph to model only the first concept.

Note that it's *not* OK to only model `Vertex List Graph` for `astar_search_no_init()`, even though it may seem to work. The `Vertex List Graph` concept is not a special case of `Incidence Graph`. It *would* be OK to model `Bidirectional Graph`; that is a special case of Incidence Graph`

Comment: Right, as I suspected. Still this doesn't answer the real question: why do all the astar_search_no_init() functions present in astar_search.hpp require VertexListGraph? The documentation says there is a version working with IncidenceGraphs and that would make sense, but I see none.

Comment: The file can be seen [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/graph/astar_search.hpp)

Comment: I see a [`inline void astar_search_no_init(const IncidenceGraph &g, ...`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html#sec:astar) documented - isn't that the one you're looking for? Never mind the (formal) names in the .hpp file, that's just implementation.